# How to clear the all form fields after successful submit in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, select, dropdown, contact-form-7

I am using contact form7 dropdowm field in my form, When i submit the form successfully, all other form fields are reset except select box field. it's show what i am select the option from the select list before form submit.

select box code : [select* state id:regState class:required-entry class:validate-select class:selectpicker class:show-menu-arrow first_as_label "States" "Alaska" "Arizona" "Arkansas" "California" "Colorado" "Connecticut"]

i am also tried the jquery based form reset it's not working.

code: jQuery(".wpcf7-form")[0].reset();

please i need help resolve this problem.

Comment: In my case, the file field isn't being cleared, even though the select fields are clearing ok, so I'm upvoting the question. I wonder if the author's issue was a javascript error on the page though...

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with **jquery** or **javascript**. add code in your footer file.

jquery

```
$("#myform").trigger('reset');
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("myform").reset();
```

Comment: you need to use your id and call this after form submit. hope this make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can try their DOM events https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

```
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {

    jQuery ( 'form.wpcf7form' )[0].reset();

}, false );
```

Or

```
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {

    jQuery ( 'form.wpcf7form' ). trigger ( 'reset' );

}, false );
```